# python extension for vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with python autocomplete in visual studio code. The only way I can trigger the autocomplete function is with the Tab or Enter key. Brackets and dot does not have any effect (or better it just hides the suggestion box and puts the bracket in place on the unfinished word e.g. -> typing **pr** in the editor would display the suggestion box with print as the first choice, if i then press bracket i end up with **pr()** instead of **print()**)
I presume there should be some settings so autocomplete would act "normally" but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is set by the shortcut key. Open the **Default Keyboard Shortcuts** (**File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**) and search for "acceptSelectedSuggestion". You will see that there are only two settings by default, the `Tab` and `Enter` keys.

[image]

If you want to add other buttons to trigger typing intellisense, right-click on one of the settings and select `Add Keybinding`,

[image]

then press the button you want to set, and press Enter to save.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use the python autocomplete extension. You can just use the `Python` extension.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just to clarify - Extensions i have installed are: Python extension, Pylance,, IntelliCode, Jupiter, jupyter keymap all made from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Tab or enter is required to actually *make a selection*. Otherwise, you could have custom function `printStuff`, and typing `pr(` would not necessarily pick the right one.

From what I can tell, PyCharm works the exact same way, so unclear what "acts normal" means in this context.

Comment: in other languages there is special characters that autocomplete ... i am not arguig the problem of pressing tab I am just saying that presing ( or . would be equivalent as to pressing tab.

Comment: I regularly code in Java, JS, Go, etc. Which languages are you referring to?

Comment: in other languages there is special characters that autocomplete -> this is the setting in vscode: acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter - it works in JS but not in python

Comment: That setting should work for all editors. According to the issues, that's a keybinding specific to the language https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26569#issuecomment-301403215